# How can I access the first attempt's yarn log?

Tags: logging, hadoop-yarn

If I use **_*attemptid*** postfix am I getting the given attempt's log? Like this:

```
yarn logs -applicationId application_11112222333333_444444_1
```

Strangely I didn't find an answer for this on the web.

UPDATE:
Let me rephrase my question:
How can I access a given attempt's yarn log?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a bit ugly but working solution in several steps (for hadoop-2.6). Basically each attempt executes in it's container. To get logs for specific container need to know applicationId, containerId, and node manager address. For example you need to get logs for appattempt_1:

1. To get info about appattempt (containerId, host url):
   `yarn applicationattempt -list application_ID_1`. You'll got something like this:

```
======================== ======== ==================== =========================== 
  ApplicationAttempt-Id    State    AM-Container-Id            Tracking-URL         
 ======================== ======== ==================== =========================== 
  appattempt_1             FAILED   container_1          https://host1:8090/blabla  
  appattempt_2             KILLED   container_2          https://host2:8090/blabla  
 ======================== ======== ==================== ===========================
```

2. To convert tracking-URL to node address:

   `$ yarn node -list -all | grep host1 | awk '{print $1}'
   host1:8041`
3. `yarn logs -applicationId application_ID_1 -containerId container_1 -nodeAddress host1:8041`

In hadoop-2.7 you can just use:

```
yarn logs -applicationId  [OPTIONS]

general options are:
 -am                      Prints the AM Container logs for
                                         this application. Specify
                                         comma-separated value to get logs
                                         for related AM Container. For
                                         example, If we specify -am 1,2,
                                         we will get the logs for the
                                         first AM Container as well as the
                                         second AM Container. To get logs
                                         for all AM Containers, use -am
                                         ALL. To get logs for the latest
                                         AM Container, use -am -1. By
                                         default, it will print all
                                         available logs. Work with
                                         -log_files to get only specific
                                         logs.
```

Comment: Unfortunately we have a common CName i the tracking URL, but I think I can figure it out. The container id is not enough for this filtering?

Comment: What's the hadoop version/distribution do you use? That answer for hadoop-2.6/CDH-5.9. For hadoop-2.7/HDP-2.5 you can use:

`
yarn logs -applicationId <application ID> 

 -am <AM Containers>  Prints the AM Container logs for this application. Specify comma-separated value to get logs for related AM Container. For
 example, If we specify -am 1,2,  we will get the logs for the first AM Container as well as the second AM Container.
`

Comment: But yes for hadoop-2.6 just container id is not enough:
 -containerId <Container ID>     ContainerId (must be specified if node
                                 address is specified)
 -nodeAddress <Node Address>     NodeAddress in the format nodename:port
                                 (must be specified if container id is
                                 specified)

Comment: My workflow (action) has failed a couple of times, but it took a different applicationId both times, and then final ran successfully with another applicationId. So, I could not really use the above command to see all the failed attempts at all. Is there a way to see them?